# While loop deletes all files and becomes stuck in loop

Tags: linux, shell-script

I'm having trouble using a while loop to delete files until a certain amount of files remain.

This is what I have:

```
touch while/151234
touch while/152355
touch while/151694
touch while/153699
touch while/156946
NUMSNAPS=$(ls while | awk '{print $1}' | wc -l)
RETAIN=2

while [ "$RETAIN" -le "$NUMSNAPS" ]; do
    OLDEST=$(ls | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1)
    rm "$OLDEST"
done
```

I cannot use find to delete these files as this is really a test to use with another third-party command. I plan on looking for snapshots with DOCTL and deleting them until a certain one remains.

Comment: You don't re-evaluate `NUMSNAPS` inside the loop.

Comment: That was it. Still learning, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a loop that tests a certain condition based on two variables that you never change. I'm assuming you were meaning to decrease the `NUMSNAPS` value by one in each iteration.

---

In the `zsh` shell, you may do

```
retain=2

rm -f while/*(DN.Om[retain+1,-1])
```

to delete all regular files (including files with hidden names) apart from the `$retain` most recently modified files.  If this happens to be several thousands of files, you may want to use `zargs` instead:

```
retain=2

autoload -U zargs
zargs -- while/*(DN.Om[retain+1,-1]) -- rm
```

If you want to order the files by name instead, then replace `Om` ("order by mtime timestamp, in decreasing order") by `On` ("order by name, in decreasing order").

You could obviously call this from another shell than `zsh` by using e.g.

```
retain=2

zsh -c 'rm -f $2/*(DN.Om[$1+1,-1])' zsh "$retain" "while"
```

This also passes the name of the directory and the number of files to retain into the in-line script, making it easier to incorporate into an existing non-`zsh` script.

---

In the `bash` shell, you don't really want to [parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985).  Instead you may want to use

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob

retain=2

set -- while/*

while [ "$#" -gt "$retain" ]; do
    rm -f "$1"
    shift
done
```

This would set the list of positional parameters to the list of files in the `while` directory (including hidden names), and then remove files form that list until there are only `retain` files left in the list.

This avoids issues with awkward filenames, and it also avoids calling `ls` once for every file removed.

This code would delete files based on their names (not by last-modified timestamp). This seems to be what your code is also attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

But why you can't get whole list and just keep number of files you need?
For example:

```
ls -r while | tail -n +${retain} | xargs echo rm
```

Comment: The author of question will not work with `ls` and files but with some output of `doctl`. And my idea in general is not to remove items one by one and counting number of items left but get full list of items, skip number of elements we want to keep and just remove all others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would fix and improve your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch while/151234
touch while/152355
touch while/151694
touch while/153699
touch while/156946

NUMSNAPS=$(ls -1 while | wc -l)
RETAIN=2

while (( RETAIN < NUMSNAPS )); do
    OLDEST=$(ls -1t while | tail -n 1)
    rm "while/$OLDEST"
    (( --NUMSNAPS ))
done
```